# Finitely generated module as an (in)finite sum of submodules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, finitely-generated

Let $R$ be a ring, $M$ be a nontrivial proper left $R$-module and $(M_\lambda)_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ be a family of submodules of $M$ such that $M = \sum_{\lambda \in \Lambda} M_\lambda$.

If $M$ is finitely generated, show that $M$ is a finite sum of those $M_\lambda$.

I really don't know what to do, this seems intuitive, but I have no clue on how to proceed.

Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Take a finite generating set $S$. Each element of $S$ belongs to the sum $\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda} M_{\lambda}$. Write what it means by definition and try to finish from there.

Comment: I don't know what your point is Mark, because any element of the finite generating set may only beloing to an infinite sum.

Comment: No. Each element of the module can be written as a finite sum of elements of the $M_\lambda$'s, by definition of the sum of modules, even if the latter is infinite. Without a notion of convergence, there wouldn't even be a definition of infinite sums (at least usually).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is easy. Suppose that a set of generators for $M$ is given by $m_1, \ldots, m_n \in M$. For each $j \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$, write
$$
m_j = r_{j, \lambda_1} x_{j, \lambda_1} + \cdots + r_{j, \lambda_{k_j}} x_{j, \lambda_{k_j}}
$$
with $x_{j, \lambda_l} \in M_{\lambda_l}$. Then the elements $x_{j, \lambda_l}$ obviously generate all of $M$, and there are finitely many of them, so that there are finitely many $M_{\lambda_l}$'s which are necessary to generate $M$.